How can I handle events for receiving streaming data and file data in WebSockets?
I have a C# websocket server application and a React web client page that connects to it.
A C# websocket server wants to convert video footage data to FFmpeg in real-time and then stream that data to a web page. However, at certain moments(eg. every 20 seconds), you want to compress the image file and other files locally, and then pass the compressed file via a websocket message as well.
This means that React needs to be able to receive these two pieces of data and process them contextually.
In this situation, how can React see the shape of the data and make the appropriate judgment to process it?
I have found some information through GPT, Cluade, but it talks about multiplexing or making it into JSON and sending it. Is this a good idea?

Convert to ffmpeg?  FFmpeg is an application

@XavierJ To explain further, we want to stream data from a third-party camera in real-time. I want to apply it to WebRTC, but since network speed is important, I want to send as little data as possible, so I want to convert it to ffmpeg with options like h.264/2800kbps and send that data.

Again FFMPEG is an application, MP4 is a streaming protocol.  It is already compressed.  You should look into M3U8 as an approach for streaming, it's going to be much cleaner than embedding video into websockets.  You can exchange m3u8 url metadata via the websocket, but let the browser download the video directly.  Wrapping in websocket will add unnecessary overhead and increase bandwidth needs.

@XavierJ Thanks for the detailed explanation, the M3U8 you are talking about is related to the HLS(HTTP Live Streaming) method, right?
I understand what you are talking about. I would like to take it a bit further and ask a question. If it's "Raw video data", do you think the same concept makes sense then?

I ask this question because I'm eventually going to use Hikrobot's MVS SDK to pass camera sensor data to a browser. I asked the question because the SDK needs to be implemented in C#, meaning I want the program to act as a data bridge between the camera and the browser, and I want to send the lowest data possible. I apologize for being a newbie and not knowing much.
